# Keeping the same step of degradation when changing the reference value

Tags: python, list, loops

I'm working on this code which goes through list of values with a loop and look for a variation (which I call degradation) over 5% from the reference value. That reference value will change if the "degradation" is over 5% and it will shift to the next value.

**Problem:**

- When we go from 1 to 0.95 it's a degradation of 5% (because 5% of 1 is 0.05 and the difference is 1 - 0.05 = 0.95) so it's good.
- But when we move to ref = 0.95 then the 5% degradation will be 0.0475 which is 0.95 - 0.0475 = 0.9025 and not 0.9 (logic in maths but not what I want).

**What I want**:

- I want the code to keep shifting ref value when the degradation is over 5% **and** at the same time keeping a 0.05 step.

```
randomlist = [1, 0.98, 0.95, 0.93, 0.9, 0.87, 0.85, 0.82, 0.8, 0.78, 0.75, 0.72, 0.7]
Degradation = 5
ref = randomlist[0]
for i in randomlist:
    if (1 - (i / ref)) * 100 > Degradation:
        ref = i
        continue
```

My code isn't considering that.

Comment: sample output please :-)

Comment: @Bharel I don't think the output is a necessity in this case, since the main focus is how to be able to consider a 0.05 step between values and not 5% from the ref value is i'm doing in the code

Comment: I don't understand the question then, sample refs for the random list would be good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find the solution:

```py
randomlist = [1, 0.98, 0.95, 0.93, 0.9, 0.87, 0.85, 0.82, 0.8, 0.78, 0.75, 0.72, 0.7]
Degradation = 10
ref = randomlist[0]
for i in randomlist:
    if round((ref - i) * 100) >= Degradation:
        ref = i
        continue
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood right what you did is reducing by 5% of the current value.

What you should do is reducing by a constant value or a percentage of the initial value.
So it would be -0.05 at each loop.

```
randomlist = [1, 0.98, 0.95, 0.93, 0.9, 0.87, 0.85, 0.82, 0.8, 0.78, 0.75, 0.72, 0.7]
Degradation = 10
five_percent_Degradation = Degradation * 0.05
ref = randomlist[0]
for i in randomlist:
    if (1 - (i / ref)) * 100 > Degradation:
        ref = i
        Degradation -= five_percent_Degradation
        print(Degradation)
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to put Degradation = 5 not 10. I'll check what you did now

Comment: The 5% degradation is now calculed dynamically, so you just have to change your value in Degradation, it doesnt matter

Comment: If you do a print of ref after the for loop, you will not see 0.95 taken as a ref value, but directly from 1 to 0.87 which is not a 5% degradation since ref value is like 13% degradation with your code (from 1 - 0.87 = 0.13)